# How to append @click navigateTo() event to v-list items props

Tags: vue-router, vuetifyjs3, nuxt3

I am using Nuxt3 with Vuetify3, and I am having trouble getting this to work:

```
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    v-model="menu"
    class="pa-4"
    temporary
  >
    <v-list
      :items="items"
      nav
      density="compact"
    />
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">
const menu = ref(false);
const items = [
  {
    title: 'Dashboard',
    props: {
      '@click': () => {
        navigateTo('./dashboard');
      },
      prependIcon: 'mdi-view-dashboard-variant-outline'
    }
  },
  {
    title: 'Orders',
    props: {
      to: './orders',
      prependIcon: 'mdi-package-variant'
    }
  }
];
</script>
```

The `Orders` list-item works as expected, but it is causing other bugs in my app with Nuxt, so I would like to use Nuxt's navigateTo() function. The Dashboard link doesn't have the click event attached.

I have also tried `'@click': navigateTo('./dashboard')` but this creates an endless navigation loop in Nuxt. I also tried `'v-on:click'` and `click () {}`, but I can't seem to get it to append the click event to the v-list-items.

Obviously I could rewrite this without the shorthand `<v-list :items="items" />`, but I'm sure there must be a way to do this shorthand.

Comment: Since event handlers are not considered component props, I don't think there's a valid way to pass it within the `props` object. You will likely need to to forego using the `:items` prop, which is probably designed for use with simpler lists, and insert a child `<v-list-item>` element utilizing `v-for` to render all your items.  A click handler added to `<v-list-item>` can run a method to navigate only if the passed in item from the `v-for` is the "dashboard" item.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I made those changes and it's working as expected. I would still like to know if it's possible to use the shorthand, if anyone has a solution.